# Exception of type 'Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Diagnostics.CollectionStartFailedHubException' was thrown.

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I wanted to profile project, but this popped out:

[image: MyProject failed to launch. Exception of type 'Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Diagnostics.CollectionStartFailedHubException' was thrown.]

The program did launch though. This happens every time I try to run CPU profiling. Is there something I should setup first before profiling?

Comment: could be the same like the other issue, that windows 7 is too old. Try a [Win10 VM with VS2017](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines)